# Approve changes in github

Tags: github

I have a git enterprise in my company and we have a system like this [documentation](https://help.github.com/articles/about-pull-request-reviews/) for review the pull request before merging into master. But here is coming a problem. People are reviewing when the branch is still in progress.
How I can do, to remove review after a new commit was done in a branch?, or check that the review is the last thing before have the button of merge pull request green?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can add a tag "work in progress" on the pull request.

https://help.github.com/articles/working-with-tags/

Comment: Yes we also has that. But for us all the pull request need to be review before merging. And I want to review at the very end of the work.

Comment: Your teammates can remove the "wip" tag after they done the development of the PR. We use it in our team, and this is very useful :

1 - a dev create the branch, and the PR with the WIP tag
2 - after the development, he removes the WIP tag
3 - the team reviews the PR
4 - the dev put the WIP tag to avoid comments on unfinished PR
... and so on, until positive review.